# Migración de Mysql a PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, laravel, postgresql

tengo mi proyecto elavorado en Laravel 5.8.29. En principio tenía una conexión a una base de datos Mysql, pero por cuestiones de implementación de una api, se tuvo que migrar toda la base de datos a PostgreSQL.

Después de investigar un poco, conseguí la forma de realizar la migración, y en efecto, logré realizar la migración, lo intuyo porque desde el pgAdmin4 puedo observar la base de datos con sus respectivas tablas.

Sin embargo, el problema de todo éste asunto, está en que laravel, sigue sacando información de la base de datos Mysql, es decir, sigue agregando, editando y eliminando la información de ésas tablas. Pero, todo lo referente a las migraciones lo está haciendo en la base de datos que se migró a PostgreSQL.En ésta última, no hay ningun campo guardado, no se guarda nada (aunque existan las respectivas tablas, la aplicación sigue guardando en mysql)

Ya modifiqué los archivos .env y database.php de laravel:

.env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=inces
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=123
```

En el otro archivo (database.php):

```
'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST',     '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],
```

Vale la pena recalcar que también apliqué la configuración necesaria al archivo php.ini. He intentado, lugo de todo esto, migrar, con los comandos nativos de laravel, fresh, refresh, hacer todo lo que me han indicado en internet y no funciona. Espero la ayuda de alguien, de antemano, gracias.

Comment: En el archivo database.php en la linea 16 colócalo de esta forma para que tome prioridad en el motor de base de datos:  'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'pgsql'),

Comment: Hola santiago, gracias por tomarte el tiempo. No lo mencioné pero eso también lo hice desde un principio y el error persiste.

Comment: Cuando utilizas la bd en postgres tienes activado mysql? seguro que hay conflicto en eso tal vez, y toma prioridad en mysql, elimina el cache de tu laravel a veces se guardan las configuraciones, pueden ser muchas cosas, pero es coMplicado dar exActamente con lo especifico. Tienes que ir probando poco a poco, o copia lo que tienes en .env a un bloc de nota  elimina el de laravel y vuelves a pegarlo con el mismo nombre, nose porque pero a mi algunas veces me a funcionado es como que se ajusta a la configuracion anterior.

Comment: Otra alternativa seria cambir el APP_KEY="aqui la encriptación" por una nueva  encriptación, que esta en .env

Comment: Sí, tengo el mysql activado, pero si desactivo, la aplicación no me funciona... es como si aún estuviese conectado a esa base de datos mysql

Comment: En cuanto a lo del APP_KEY, no sé exactamente a qué encriptación te refieres. Digo, por cuál encriptación cambiarla, mejor dicho.

Comment: Fijate que tu archivo: "env.example" no este con las configuraciones de mysql

Comment: Para generar una nueva clave dijata en la consola de tu proyecto: php artisan key:generate , y generará la nueva clave para su APP_KEY=  en tu archivo  .env

Comment: El "env.example" tenía la configuración del mysql aún, la cambié. Generé la nueva clave del proyecto con el comando php artisan key... Y nada, sigue todo igual. ¿Crees que pueda ser la ip de los servidores? mysql tiene la 127.0.0.1 al igual que el Postgres

Comment: Utiliza estos dos comando para limpiar tu proyecto laravel: php artisan cache:clear  y  php artisan config:cache  , otro consejo que te doy es que utilices otro navegador  pues los navagadores guardan las configuraciones antiguas, o utiliza el modo incognito del navegador para probar tu proyecto laravel.

Comment: el servidor local 127.0.0.1 no es el problema puesto que es para que el proyecto corra  junto con el php. y la bd es un tema aparte.

Comment: Santiago muchas gracias. Al parecer debía ejecutar el comando "php artisan config:cache" para limpiar la configuración de la configuracion. Gracias por tomarte el tiempo, Solucionado.}

Comment: Es un gusto ayudar, que tengas un Excelente día!